# Redirect to index.jsp after login using Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet to handle `/Login`.

```
String tempUsername = request.getParameter("username").trim();
String tempPassword = request.getParameter("password").trim();
String message = null;

if(tempUsername != null && tempPassword != null) {
    String username = tempUsername;
    String password = tempPassword;
    Staff staff = new Staff();

    try {
        Facade facade = new Facade();
        Staff result = facade.getStaff(username, password);

        if(result != null) {
            // response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/Home"); // Success but didn't redirect to `/Home`
            System.out.println("Success");
        }
        else {
            // request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException | NamingException e) {
        // SQL Error
    }
    finally {
        request.setAttribute("message", message);   
    }

}
else {
    // Empty field(s)
}
```

I have another servlet to handle `/Home` where `index.jsp` will be displayed if login success.

However, currently if login success, the page is still stay at `/Login` with only a blank page, instead of redirecting to `/Home`.

How can I redirect to `/Home` after login success?

I'm new in using Servlet as well as Eclipse. I just started learning J2EE and Eclipse. Still exploring.

- Edit(s):
- I changed the `forward()` and `sendRedirect()` to `println()`. When I used the wrong username and password, "Fail" is printed out. But when I used the correct details, there is nothing printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `sendRedirect()` - `forward()` is more appropriate since you're redirecting the request on the same server (using a relative path). If you insist on using  `sendRedirect()` - use the pull URL.

Comment: I'm new in using Servlet. Previously I am directing those request to `jsp`, instead of through `Servlet`. I don't know why the page is not displayed, even though I do have `index.jsp`. I tried with `forward()` and `sendRedirect()`, but both also directed to blank page, with the same directory `/Login` instead of `/Home`.

Comment: @Chin `forward()` does not change the url (but you can sniff the browser and see what call is being made). The blank page is probably some kind of error that happens on `/home` - but since you didn't post the code of that page it's difficult to say what could be the reason for that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that absolutePath thing if you have the mapping of the url of the servlet you want to redirect in the web.xml or as annotation this simple lines shall do the work

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher=servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/Home");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Or this

```
response.sendRedirect("/Home");
```

Comment: I edited the code a bit. Why is the "Success" is not printed out, but "Fail" can be printed out?

Comment: did u get any exception try printing the exception using e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know how to explain this. But there is no `SQLException` and `Exception`. But I restarted the server still the same. I re-launched Eclipse, there is no error too.

Comment: did u try using the generic exception instead of sqlexception or namingexception?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening, but I deleted the Servlet and then pasted back the same code, and somwhow it's work.